# Some requests are not replicated by nginx mirror directives

Tags: nginx

### Problem

I thought the request on nginx mirror directives replication was done asynchronously, not waiting for a response from the old environment, is that wrong?

#### background

I am using mirror directives in nginx to duplicate and flush requests for the new environment. However, I am having trouble because the number of requests sent to the new environment (mirror) does not match the total number of requests sent to the old environment. Specifically, the new environment (mirror) has a certain number of requests less than the old environment.

#### configfile

The configuration is shown below.

```
server{
    server_name   example.com;

    listen       80  default_server;

    proxy_set_header Host    $host;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    log_subrequest on;

    mirror_request_body on;

    location /v1/legacy {
        proxy_pass    http://exmaple.legacy.com/v1/legacy;
        mirror   /mirror/new;
    }

    location /mirror/new {
       proxy_pass    http://exmaple.new.com/v1/new;
       proxy_connect_timeout 10000ms;
       proxy_read_timeout 10000ms;
    }
```

requests will be duplicated even if URL end with a '/'. Also, this application basically returns a response within 0.01 seconds.

The following commands were used to count logs.

```
grep -E  "/v1/legacy/? [0-9]+.*" access.log | wc -l
grep -E  "/v1/new/? [0-9]+.*" access.log | wc -l
```

Checking the nginx access log `var/log/nginx/access.log`, we know that the following request with a remarkably long processing time is recorded in the access log only for the old environment and does not seem to have been sent to the new environment.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [03/Oct/2022:16:30:47 +0900] "POST /v1/before HTTP/1.1" /v1/before 400 0 1 27.912 27.912
```

@logformat

```
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr [$time_local] "$request" $uri '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent '
                      '$connection_requests $connection_time $request_time';
```

I wondered if it would not be replicated if the response is too slow and the client disconnects..

Comment: IDK but notice that the status code is **400 Bad Request** which may also be a reason it didn't get to the mirror.

Comment: Thank you for comment.  Yes, is is.　However, some of the other status 400 requests are being replicated properly. It certainly seems that one of the reasons is that the status must be 400, but is there a condition for the request to be replicated on the MIRROR side...?